# How to make template engine process thymeleaf pages from both database and filesystem

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, template-engine

I am creating a springboot app that needs to process thymeleaf code that is stored in a database alongside general thymeleaf pages stored in the filesystem. My question is what is the best approach for it?

First, I've tried creating two different resolvers and adding them to the template engine. Then I've tried creating two separate template engines with separate resolvers. The second try worked, but I do not think that it is the correct approach cause the template is costly.

1st

```
public SpringTemplateEngine engine() {
            SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
            engine.addTemplateResolver(stringTemplateResolver());
                engine.addTemplateResolver(thymeleafTemplateResolver());
            return engine;
        }
@Bean
            public ClassLoaderTemplateResolver thymeleafTemplateResolver() {
             var resolver 
                  = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
             resolver.setPrefix("templates/");
             resolver.setSuffix(".html");
             resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
             resolver.setOrder(1);


              //  templateResolver.
                return resolver;
            }


         @Bean
        public StringTemplateResolver stringTemplateResolver() {
            var resolver = new StringTemplateResolver();
            resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
            resolver.setCacheable(false);
            resolver.setOrder(2);
            return resolver;
        }
```

2nd

```
public SpringTemplateEngine thymeleafEngine() {
            SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
                engine.addTemplateResolver(thymeleafTemplateResolver());
            return engine;
        }
public SpringTemplateEngine dbEngine() {
            SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
                engine.addTemplateResolver(stringTemplateResolver());
            return engine;
        }
```

for the first try, I can either use one or another (based on which I add first). If I add thymeleaf first, it will load the regular page normally but will process the thymeleaf from the database as a path, not as content and vice versa. What I want to accomplish is to have one engine that will process the path from the controller as a path to the .html file and that will process the string content from the database as the actual page.

Thanks for your time!